# Adding Keywords not showing up in Template

Tags: django

Hi I am adding keywords for meta tag in the templates,

I don't know why they are not showing up when I inspect the page, noting that the other things in the models is showing such title, image and the rest.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="  ">
```

Here is the models.py :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title             = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    keywords          = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here are the views:

```
def products(request):
    context = {
        'items': Item.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "products.html", context)
```

here is the template:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block head_title %} Welcome to {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
                    {% for item in object_list %}
                    {% block keywords %} {{item.keywords}}{% endblock %}
                    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: A block can only be modified once, if you override it a second time, the "old" value is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. you did not pass an `object_list` to the context, you passed a variable named `items` to the template; and
2. if you modify the block (here `keywords`) multiple times, only the last one will persist.

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block head_title %} Welcome to {% endblock %}
{% block keywords %}{% for item in items %}{{ item.keyword }}{% endfor %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    …
{% endblock content %}
```